# How to fix 'Element Not Found' exception C#

Tags: c#, exception, element

I was using **NAudio and a timer** to get some audio values, and it was working previously but it's now throwing a

> 'Element not found' exception (Exception from HRESULT: `0x80070490`)

from the second line of this code:

```
NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.Render, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Role.Console);
```

I can't think of anything I changed in the code. All the references to **NAudio** are, to my knowledge, present. 
What does this exception mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: I've tried this but I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: Errors produced by the audio driver stack tend to be unspecific.  But it looks like your machine config changed and you no longer have a default audio output device.  Make sure programs can still produce sounds and that you can playback an audio file.  Rebooting the machine might help.

Comment: I get the same error when I disable my microphone (I'm searching for capture devices).